# How can i use $$ to get the value of $b=211

Tags: php

```
<?php
 $a = 1;
 $b= &$a;
 $b = 2$b;
```

How can i make the value of `$b` to 211.
If i will echo those to like
echo $a.$b;
Output should be 1211.
I can't use + as it is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do the following:

```
<?php
 $a = 1;
 $b = "2".$a.$a;

 echo $c = "1".$b;
?>
```

This will asign $b = 211
and final output will be 1211

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot to concat as string and [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to convert string to integer:

```
<?php
 $a = 1;
 $b = 2 . $a . $a; // 211 as string
 $b_int = intval($b); // 211 as integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ues `+`, you can use `.` to concate string.

```
2 . $a . $b
```